# Query regarding textual classification data inherently residing in high dimensional space by default

Tags: text, machine-learning, svm

I have read in a lot of support vector machine books and technical papers, an assumption that many of the authors make for choosing a linear kernel for most text classification task.

They say something like, since the data in text classification problems already resides in a high dimensional space, it is enough to choose a linear kernel to separate the data while attempting to classify the data using SVMs.

My understanding of this assumption is as follows:

In any text classification task, the number of features (in many cases certain important words that we are looking for in the documents) that will be chosen for the classification task will mostly be very high and this is what is meant by the data residing in a high dimensional space.

Is my understanding of the assumption accurate? If not I would like for someone to try to shed some light on this assumption.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it you are correct.

- Each features corresponds to a dimension.
- Higher dimension => Higher probability of separation.
- Non-linear kernels only transforms the data (non-linearly) to a higher dimension to increase the probability of separation and thus not needed in the case with many features.

I can recommend reading the lectures about SVM's and similar from: http://www.csc.kth.se/utbildning/kth/kurser/DD2427/bik12/Schedule.php
That's the best resource I know in the subject. Short and to the point.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Also I was wondering if you knew of any online resources where I could gain some practice with SVM's ,like a site that provides some sample data and I can generate a feature vector and play around with classification of the data?